# F# function types

Tags: f#

Im practicing f# and found this example, where I have to write f# function of the following types:

fun1: ’a -> (’a -> ’b) -> ’b

fun2: (’a -> ’b) -> ((’a -> ’c) -> ’d) -> (’b -> ’c) -> ’d

fun3: (’a -> ’b -> ’c) -> ’a * ’b -> ’c

fun4: (’a -> ’b -> ’a) -> ’a * ’b -> ’a

fun5: (’a -> ’a -> ’a) -> ’a * ’a -> ’a

my solution so far

```
// fun1: ’a -> (’a -> ’b) -> ’b
let fun1 x k = k x

// fun2: (’a -> ’b) -> ((’a -> ’c) -> ’d) -> (’b -> ’c) -> ’d
let fun2 f t k = failwith "Not implemented"

// fun3: (’a -> ’b -> ’c) -> ’a * ’b -> ’c
let fun3 f (x, y) = f x y 

// fun4: (’a -> ’b -> ’a) -> ’a * ’b -> ’a
let fun4 f (x, y) = failwith "Not implemented"

// fun5: (’a -> ’a -> ’a) -> ’a * ’a -> ’a
let fun5 f (x, y) = failwith "Not implemented"
```

And I have done fun1 and fun 3 successfully and need help with the others. Anyone that can give me some tips? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important that you do understand the execrises you were given, and Tomas explained everything nicely. Anymay here are some solutions how you could do it. Or at least, how i would solve it.

```ml
(* fun1: ’a -> (’a -> ’b) -> ’b *)
let fun1 x f =
    f x

(* fun2: (’a -> ’b) -> ((’a -> ’c) -> ’d) -> (’b -> ’c) -> ’d *)
let fun2 f h g =
    h (f >> g)

(* fun3: (’a -> ’b -> ’c) -> ’a * ’b -> ’c *)
let fun3 f (x,y) = 
    f x y

(* fun4: (’a -> ’b -> ’a) -> ’a * ’b -> ’a *)
let fun4 (f : 'a -> 'b -> 'a) (x,y) = 
    f x y

(* fun5: (’a -> ’a -> ’a) -> ’a * ’a -> ’a *)
let fun5 (f : 'a -> 'a -> 'a) (x,y) = 
    f x y
```

Just as a interesting side-note. `fun1` is bacially the `|>` function or operator in F#.

Prove:

```
let add1 x = x + 1

printfn "%d" ((|>) 10 add1)
printfn "%d" (fun1 10 add1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll add some hints rather than posting a solution:

```
// fun2: (’a -> ’b) -> ((’a -> ’c) -> ’d) -> (’b -> ’c) -> ’d
let fun2 f t k = failwith "Not implemented"
```

Here, `f` is of type `'a -> 'b` and `k` is of type `'b -> 'c`. Note that you could compose these two. With that, you should then be able to invoke the function `t` that requires an argument of type `'a -> 'c`.

```
// fun5: (’a -> ’a -> ’a) -> ’a * ’a -> ’a
let fun5 f (x, y) = failwith "Not implemented"
```

Here, the function gets a function `f` that can be called with two arguments of type `'a` to produce a result of type `'a`. You also got two arguments, `x` and `y` (passed as a tuple) that you can use. The structure of the type is quite similar to that in `fun3`, but if you want to write this function without type annotations, you'll somehow need to convince the compiler that all the type parameters are the same one, i.e., `'a`. You could do that by calling `f` multiple times. If you call `f x y` in one place and `f y x` in another, the compiler will know that the type of `x` and `y` has to be the same.

```
// fun4: (’a -> ’b -> ’a) -> ’a * ’b -> ’a
let fun4 f (x, y) = failwith "Not implemented"
```

This is again similar to `fun3` and `fun4`, but again - to do this without type annotations - you'll somehow need to convince the compiler that the type of the first argument of `f` is the same as the type that it returns. The best way to do this is to pass the result of `f` back to `f` (as the first argument in another call). That forces the compiler to unify the types.